# Executable not linking to the my desired dynamic library

Tags: dynamic-linking, libc, dynamic-library, mpich, rpath

I have built and installed mpich from source (mpich-3.4.1.tar.gz), using the steps given in 'https://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.4.1/mpich-3.4.1-README.txt'. I want the resultant executables to be dynamically linked to libraries specified in the path '/home/myname/mylibs'. So, before calling ./configure, I have set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH as:
`setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/myname/mylibs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Inside the directory '/home/myname/mylibs' I have soft linked 'libc.so.6' and 'libstdc++.so.6' to my desired libraries, as I do not want the resultant executables to link to dynamic libraries from path /lib64/. I was able to build and install mpich in my machine. However, when I call 'ldd' on one of the executables (hydra_pmi_proxy) that were generated, I see the following:

`$ ldd /home/myname/mpich-3.4.1_install/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy`

`libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f32f9eef000)`

`libstdc++.so.6 => /home/myname/mylibs/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f32f9542000)`

The rpath seems to be set to my desired path '/home/myname/mylibs' as shown below:

`$ readelf -d /home/myname/mpich-3.4.1_install/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy | egrep "RPATH|RUNPATH"`

`0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/home/myname/mylibs]`

As shown above, libstdc++.so.6 is pointing to my desired library, but libc.so.6 is still pointing to /lib64/libc.so.6. I want libc.so.6 to point to /home/myname/mylibs/libc.so.6
Is there anything I can do to make this possible?

I do not want my exe to be dynamically linked to libraries in `/lib64/` because when I launch my MPI program on multiple machines it seems 'hydra_pmi_proxy' is trying to dynamically link to the `/lib64/libc.so.6` of the machine on which a certain process is running. (Most likely, it spawns a child process on the new machine which in turn dynamically links to /lib64/libc.so.6 of that machine). I have seen that I am getting an error when one of the mpi processes tries to run on any machine in which /lib64/libc.so.6 is pointing to an older version. The error is:
`` /home/myname/mpich-3.4.1_install/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/myname/mpich-3.4.1_install/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy) ``.
When I login to this machine, in which it is failing, and do `strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC_2`, I do not see GLIBC_2.17 listed. Whereas, on all other machines, on which the mpi processes are running successfully, I see GLIBC_2.17 listed on running 'strings'. So, my intention is to make all executables to dynamically link to only libraries at  "/home/myname/mylibs/". Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want the resultant executables to link to dynamic libraries from path /lib64/

`libc.so.6` is a special case. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) to understand why.

If you really want to isolate your binaries from libraries in `/lib64/...`, you must:

1. configure build and install into `/home/myname/mylibs/` a new version of GLIBC (symlinking isn't sufficient) and
2. set your `--dynamic-linker` and `--rpath` to point into `mylibs`.

That said, you didn't explain *why* you don't want to link libraries from `/lib64`. http://xyproblem.info might be relevant here.

Comment: I have also added the reason for not wanting to link to /lib64/, based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I also have the following questions to the solution you have provided: (1) For your sol. (2), where do I use the '--dynamic-linker' and '--rpath' switch (since I am not directly using g++ but using scripts provided by mpich for building. The scripts are ./configure, make, make install). Do I modify the makefile? or do I add the switch with the configure script. I am not familiar with the process of building from source as I am doing it for the first time. (2) For reasons given in your sol (1), will the switches help in my case?